# cannot find next item in findNext loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I loop through Items in an array `raArray` which I want to find in a Table. However, I cannot seem to get the code to work to find the next result for the array element with `FindNext`. Either I get stuck in an infinite Do loop, or, when I compare the `raArray.adress` with the `m_strAdress` following the `FindNext` I exit the loop after the search query is found a second time.

I don't quite get what i am doing wrong, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext was not helpful to me.

```
Dim raArray as Range
Dim m_strAddress  as String
dim wksDeviation as Worksheet
dim iC as Long


For iC = 1 To 51

Set raArray = wksDeviation.Range("E:E").Find(arrAllYield(1, iC - 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)        
    If raArray Is Nothing Then
    
        Debug.Print arrAllYield(1, iC - 1) & " Nothing found"        
    
    Else          
      m_strAddress = raArray.Address            
       If Not raArray Is Nothing Then         
           
         Do                        
             Set raArray =  wksDeviation.Range("E:E").FindNext(wksDeviation.Range("E:E").Find(What:=arrAllYield(1, iC - 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=                    False, SearchFormat:=False))                 
         Loop While raArray.Address <> m_strAddress And Not raArray Is Nothing
           
       End If            
    End If
Next iC
```

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong are greatly appreciated. I am quite stuck.

Comment: stab in the dark, I think you have to "reset" your array before you iterate your next loop. Side question, I don;t think I've used .find, is it more efficient that .filter?

Comment: what do you mean by "reset" ? If I use "find" w/o findnext, I can locate the term in my table and it iterates nicely through the array, however, it omits more than one occurence of the search term. Not sure filter would work, since i need the adress of the result to get the content of the cell next to it.